# Validating lower and upper Ascii in Python

Tags: python, function, ascii

Grateful for any help on the problem, trying to have the password validate based on containing Ascii lower and upper. I have got alternative solutions to function but am trying to determine why the starred below (line 7) below isn't working as intended. Thanks

```
#password program

#password subroutine
def password(userInput):
  result = "passed"
  #check for uppercase using ASCII values
  **res = any(ord(ele) != 32 and ord(ele) <= 64 or ord(ele) >= 91 for ele in userInput)
  #check if length is less than 8
  if len(userInput) < 8:
    result = "failed"**
  #check if there is a number
  elif userInput.isalpha():
    result = "failed"
  #check if there is an uppercase character using ASCII values    
  elif str(res) != "True":
    result ="failed"
  
  return result  
  
  

#main program
#set condition for continuous loop
passwordChecker = True
check = False
while passwordChecker == True:
  print("This is a password checker program","\n","Enter your password and this program will check it","\n")
  print("The criteria are:","\n","\n")
  print("Must have at least 8 characters","\n","must have at least 1 UPPERCASE, 1 lowercase, and 1 number")
  print("Must be able to to be used more than once","\n","Must not crash if any of the above criteria are not met","\n") 
  print("Enter 'End' to exit this checker")
  #get user input
  userInput = input("Please enter your password: ")
  #quit loop
  if userInput == 'End' or userInput == 'end' or userInput == 'END':
    passwordChecker = False
    break
  #output result of password check
  passFail = password(userInput)
  if passFail == "failed":
    print('\n',"Your password has failed at least one of the checks",'\n','\n')
    #run the checker again
    check = input("Would you like to try another password (Y/N)?").upper()
    if check != "Y":
      passwordChecker = False
  else:
    print("Your password has passed all of the checks")
    break

print("Thank you for using this program")
```

Comment: Why not use [str.islower](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) and `isupper` instead of these conditions on `ord`?

Comment: By the way, `if str(res) != "True":` should be `if res` because res is a boolean value that evalutates to true or false anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits


def password(userInput):
    if len(userInput) < 8:
        print("Password too short")
        return False

    for characterSet in (ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits):
        if not any(c in characterSet for c in userInput):
            return False

    print("Password ok")
    return True


password('Password3')
```

Out:

```
Password ok
```